# ebs or CCavenue payment gateways integration in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, payment-gateway, payment-processing, ccavenue

I am very new to PHP. I downloaded the software from prestashop and developed my site.
Is it possible to integrate payment gateways from EBS or CCavenue? because I want to use any one of them in my prestashop site. I found posts related to PayPal only.

Please let me know the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

EBS integration is quite straight-forward for prestashop. Once you get EBS account, go over to downloads section and you can get the EBS module for prestashop there. Download it, unzip and copy the folder named "EBS" to your modules directory.

Post this, you can see EBS as available module in admin. Install it, and add credentials in configuration section. You could start using TEST mode almost instantly. Good luck with your website.

Comment: Yes the module is free to download

Answer (score 0):

now there is a readymade ccavenue prestashop module that works with the old and latest version of Prestashop. You can download this here http://addons.prestashop.com/en/payments-gateways-prestashop-modules/21391-ccavenue.html